# unable to post values to api using axios in redux

Tags: redux, axios, redux-form

I am trying to post data from a redux-form to an api server using axios.My action creator for posting the data looks like this:

```
//Action creator for submitting edited post
export function submitEditedPost(values, callback) {
  const request = axios.post(`${API}/posts`, {headers}, {values});
    return dispatch => {
      return request.then((data) => {
        callback();
        console.log(data)
        dispatch({
          type:SUBMIT_POST,
          payload: data
        })
      })
    }
}
```

My `onSubmit()` methos of the form where the action-creator is called looks like this:

```
  onSubmit(values) {
        var id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(-8);
        var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

        const formData = {};
     for (const field in this.refs) {
       formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
     }
        formData.id = id;
        formData.timestamp = d;
         console.log('-->', formData);
        this.props.submitEditedPost(formData, () => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }
```

When I try to console.log the edited values,I can see it correctly,but I am not able to post the edited values and update the api. The error message is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: post_error]

How do I proceed? Can someone please help me with this issue?

**EDIT 1:** My whole action file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_POSTS = 'fetch_posts';
export const CREATE_POST = 'create_post';
export const FETCH_POST = 'fetch_post';
export const DELETE_POST ='delete_post';
export const EDIT_POST = 'edit_post';
export const SUBMIT_POST = 'submit_post';

let token ;
if(!token)
  token = localStorage.token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(-8)
const API = 'http://localhost:3001';
const headers = {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' :'token'
                }



//Action creator for fetching posts from the API server
export function fetchPosts() {
  const URL = `${API}/posts`;
  const request = axios.get(URL,{headers});

  return dispatch => {
        return request.then(({data}) => {
          console.log(data);
          dispatch({
            type : FETCH_POSTS,
            payload : data
          })
        })
  }
}

//Action Creator for creating posts
export function createPosts(values, callback) {

  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post(`${API}/posts`,values,{headers})
      .then((data) => {
        callback();
        console.log(data)
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: data
      })
    })
  }
}

//Action Creator for displaying a selected post
export function fetchPost(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`${API}/posts/${id}`,{headers});

    return dispatch => {
      return request.then(({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
        type: FETCH_POST,
        payload: data
        })
      })
    }
}

//Action creator for deleting post
export function deletePost(id, callback) {
  const request = axios.delete(`${API}/posts/${id}`, {headers})
            .then(() => callback());

  return {
    type: DELETE_POST,
    payload: id
  }
}


//Action creator for editing post
export function editPost(id, callback) {
  const request = axios.get(`${API}/posts/${id}`,{headers});
    return dispatch => {
      return request.then((data) => {
        callback();
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
          type: EDIT_POST,
          payload: data
        })
      })
    }
}

//Action creator for submitting edited post
export function submitEditedPost(id, values, callback) {
  console.log(values, 'values')
  console.log(id, 'id')
  const request = axios.put(`${API}/posts/${id}`, {values}, {headers});
    return dispatch => {
      return request.then((res) => {
        callback();
        console.log("response", res)
        dispatch({
          type:SUBMIT_POST,
          payload: res
        })
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is due to server side `Joi` validations... so put your server side code also...

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I have posted a new question which is related to this question, can you please have a look at that.This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249466/unable-to-update-reducer-state-in-redux

Comment: @pranami, where is the `ROOT_URL` of your api? I don't see it passed into your `axios.post()`. Could you post the whole file, in other words from `import axios from 'axios';` down to what you have posted so far.

Comment: The `ROOT_URL` should be the first argument passed into `axios.post()` and the second argument would be the data, in this case `values`. And why do you have your `payload` as `data` instead of `request`?

Comment: @Daniel I have added the whole file in an edit above.The action creator I am talking about is at the end of the file.The issue that i am facing is I can see the eidted post in my state in redux devtools,but it appears as a child object of the main post object.It doesn't update the current post in the state.Can you please have a look?

Comment: @Daniel I have mentioned the above issue in a new question.Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249466/unable-to-update-reducer-state-in-redux .I have added the screenshots of the state here.Maybe this will make the issue clear for you.