# Unable to update reducer state in redux

Tags: redux

I have a redux app which enables users to post something(like a blog post which contains only a title and body).The user can edit the post whenever they want to.I am not able to update the reducer,i.e. I just want to update the title and the body for that particular **"id"**. I am trying to update the state in my **reducer** as shown below:

```
case SUBMIT_POST:
        let id = action.payload.id;
      return {
          ...state,
          [id]: {
            ...state[id],
            title: action.payload.title,
            body: action.payload.body
          }
        };
```

My **action-creator** looks like this:

```
//Action creator for submitting edited post
export function submitEditedPost(id, values, callback) {
  const request = axios.put(`${API}/posts/${id}`, {values}, {headers});
    return dispatch => {
      return request.then((res) => {
        callback();
        console.log(res.data.values)
        dispatch({
          type:SUBMIT_POST,
          payload: res.data.values
        })
      })
    }
}
```

How to update the reducer with the new edited title and body for that particular post id?

**EDIT 1:**

I am calling the action creator in my form **onSubmit()** method as shown below:

```
       onSubmit(values) {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        const formData = {};
     for (const field in this.refs) {
       formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
     }
        formData.id = id;
       console.log('-->', formData);
        this.props.submitEditedPost(id, formData, () => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }
```

**EDIT 2:** Screenshot of the action in reducer is shown below:

[image: reducer]

**EDIT 3:** My entire reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POST, CREATE_POST, EDIT_POST, SUBMIT_POST } from '../actions/posts_action';

export default function(state = {posts: {} }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
      // const post = action.payload.data;
      // const newState  = { ...state,  };
      // newState[post.id] = post;
      // return newState;
      return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};

    case FETCH_POSTS:

     return {posts: { ...state.posts, ...(_.mapKeys(action.payload,'id'))}};

    case CREATE_POST:
      return {...state, [ action.payload.id]: action.payload};

    case EDIT_POST:
        return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};

    case SUBMIT_POST:
    console.log(action.payload);
        let id = action.payload.id;
      return {
          ...state,
          [id]: {
            ...state[id],
            title: action.payload.title,
            body: action.payload.body
          }
        };

     default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

**EDIT 4** : Screenshot of redux-dev-tools:

[image: redux-dev-tools]

Comment: Your code seems correct. How does the actual action looks like? what happens upon dispatch?

Comment: @OrB I have pasted my code above in an edit which is for my form onSubmit( ) method where I am callinng the action creator.Can you please have a look?

Comment: Did you make sure that the action is being dispatched properly (i.e. being caught by the reducer)? if so, how does it look like?

Comment: @OrB I tried to console.log the action in my reducer.I have uploaded a screenshot of the result above.The edited values are being received in the reducer.

Comment: Is this only the `payload` portion of the action, or the entire thing? is the action being caught by the `case` statement?

Comment: Actually I tried filtering out only the values form the data in my action creator,so the payload in my action creator looks like this `payload: res.data.values` .So,yeah,tihs is what I get in the reducer.Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163140/discussion-between-or-b-and-pranami).

Comment: @pranami Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary no,its not yet resolved.I am trying to check the state in redux dev tools and I can see what's causing the issue.but I am not able to figure out how to resolve.I will put up a screenshot of the state above.Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Can we connect with team viewer?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I don't have team viewer installed in my system.If you want I can set it up,but it might take sometime.Do,you want me to set it up?Also,I have pasted the screenshot of redux-dev-tools above.The main problem is the updated state is being saved under a new object called values and the original post is not getting updated.Why is this happening,can you please check once.Also,if you want I will try the teamviewer.

Comment: Install team viewer... I am sure to resolve it

Comment: okay,just give me few mins.will install and let you know.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary sorry for the late reply.I have installed teamview and created an account.So,how to proceed now?sorry,I am new to this software

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163185/discussion-between-ashish-choudhary-and-pranami).